# Bootstrap Navbar isn't centered

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I've been working with bootstrap but I can't seem to center the elements of the navbar.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">

      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="mr-2"><path d="M23 19a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4l2-3h6l2 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z"></path><circle cx="12" cy="13" r="4"></circle></svg>
        <strong>Example</strong>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToBQZ.png

Not only is one section not aligned with the other three but I want all 4 of these items to be in the center of the Nav Bar, not to the right. In different documentations they show that the position of the navbar is different but I'm not entirely sure how to do this and the misaligned elements. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe change `justify-content-between` to `justify-content-center` on that outer `div`?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to close the  tag 
And for centering the nav you can use margin:auto trick

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">

      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="mr-2"><path d="M23 19a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4l2-3h6l2 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z"></path><circle cx="12" cy="13" r="4"></circle></svg>
        <strong>Example</strong></a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav" style="margin: auto;">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```